# Divide and count the number of divisions successively

Tags: vba, function, excel

So I am trying to get the number of divisions required to divide the two integers `N` and `D` successively till the remainder is greater than or equal to `0.000001`. I don't know where I am wrong.

Is the data type used for `N`, `D` and `Z` wrong, or something else?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Ediv()

    Dim N As Integer
    Dim D As Integer
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer

  With Sheets("Functions")

        N = Cells(16, "B").Value
        D = Cells(16, "C").Value

     If D < 1 Then
     MsgBox "Divisor is less than 1 enter value greater than 1"
     Exit Sub
     Else
     End If

     intCount = 0


      Do While Z >= 0.000001
          Z = N / D
          intCount = intCount + 1
          N = Z
      Loop

Cells(16, "D").Value = intCount
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try it with `Dim N As Double, D As Double, Z As Double`. An integer cannot by its nature contain a decimal portion of a mixed number; only 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks but still no change.

Comment: Provide some examples of what is in B16:C16 and what you are expecting.

Comment: @Jeeped example: B16 = 3 and C16 = 10 then intcount  last value will be 6 since it takes total 6 time to divide B16 by C16 to get result less greater than or equal to 0.000001

first iteration - 3/10 = 0.3 
second iteration - 0.3/10 = 0.03
third iteration - 0.03/10 = 0.003
.
so on till

sixth iteration - 0.000003/10 = 0.0000003

the seventh iteration would result it value less than 0.0000003 then it will exit with intcount value and print it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of trouble areas. Please see comments in the following.

```
Sub Ediv()

    Dim N As Double    '<~~ Integers cannot be decimal numbers
    Dim D As Double    '<~~ ^ same ^ 
    Dim Z As Double    '<~~ ^ same ^
    Dim intCount As Long '<~~ might be a long count

    With Sheets("Functions")

        N = .Cells(16, "B").Value  '<~~ these were Cells, not .Cells so they were not explicitly children of the Functions worksheet
        D = .Cells(16, "C").Value  '<~~^ same ^

        If D < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Divisor is less than 1 enter value greater than 1"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        intCount = 0


        Z = N / D  '<~~ Z was only initialized not assigned so it was zero
        Do While Z >= 0.000001
            Z = N / D
            intCount = intCount - CBool(Z >= 0.000001)  '<~~only increment if it will go into another loop; True is -1 in VBA.
            N = Z
        Loop
        'intCount = intCount -1 'decrement by 1 if not conditionally incremented
        .Cells(16, "D").Value = intCount  '<~~ fixed parent worksheet here as well
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Nice :) Ah you have also started using `'<~~ ` :D

Comment: @santosh - per your sample of 3 & 10, I came up with 7. I realize that `intCount ` should only be incremented if it is going into another loop. See above in 2 minutes.

Comment: @Jeeped yes that was the only problem but I decremented it before printing it's value

Comment: @Santosh - I commented out your edit as I had already added conditional incrementing. If no passes are made, your method would result in -1 rather than zero.

Comment: @jeeped I have one question do you know how to convert the 12 hour time to 24 hour format time using vba e.g. 1:30 pm will be 1330 ?

Comment: @Santosh - My VBE's Immediate window says `?format(timevalue("1:30 pm"), "hhmm")` yields `1330`.

Comment: @Jeeped I don't want to use format function I want to make a new function